# Yii - Change column in CGridView for another model's field

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

In my model (let's say *Model A*) I have a field corresponding to the id of another model (*Model B*). In a `CGridView` composed of Model A items, instead of showing the id of Model B, I want to show another field of that model instance.

Here's how I am showing my `CGridView`;

```
$dataProvider =  new CArrayDataProvider('Model A');
$dataProvider->setData($model_A_Data); // $model_A_data is an array of Model A Objects

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'data-id',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, //$objects->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        array('header'=>'Model A Id', 'name'=>'id'),
        array('header'=>'Name', 'name'=>'name'),
        array('header'=>'Date', 'name'=>'date_created'),
        array('header'=>'Model B Id', 'name'=>'model_b_id'), // *HERE SHOW ANOTHER FIELD OF MODEL B*
    ),  
));
```

How can I change that column in order to show another field of model B clasS?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure this `$model_A_Data` array of arrays contains all the columns and CGridView will display the columns.

Comment: You have any relation in model_a with model_b ?

Comment: Yes, there is a relation set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to solve this after discovering the `$data` var in `CGridView` which holds the corresponding row data.

Simply add this:

```
array('name'=>'Model B Another Field',
      'value'=> 'ModelB::model()->FindByPk($data->id)->another_field'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

say in `Model A` i have a relation

```
array('modelbrelationname','ModelB','id'),
```

So You can have the value like this

```
$dataProvider =  new CArrayDataProvider('Model A');
$dataProvider->setData($model_A_Data); // $model_A_data is an array of Model A Objects

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'data-id',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, //$objects->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        array('header'=>'Model A Id', 'name'=>'id'),
        array('header'=>'Name', 'name'=>'name'),
        array('header'=>'Date', 'name'=>'date_created'),
        array('header'=>'Model B Id', 'value'=>'modelbrelationname.id'), // *HERE SHOW ANOTHER FIELD OF MODEL B*
    ),  
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out another solution. This might as well work, haven't tried it though. Thanks anyway. Cheers!